# What is the least minimal privilege API Key configuration for a public read-only Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to get a Google Sheets API Credentials with the least privileges (Viewer) to only access publicly available Google Sheets.

What is the best API Credential configuration for it?

I'm currently using a Service Account with a "Viewer" Role. But it gives access to all of my resources which is something that I don't want.

I know I should create a custom role and assign specific permission to it. What would be the permission for me to do so?

Comment: Google Sheets does not support IAM roles (yet). The service account requires no IAM roles. When creating the Access Token specify one of these scopes: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly` OR `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets`. Next share the Sheet with the service account. If you are using Workplace, use impersonation. Edit your question and show how you are using the service account to create the token and use the token to access Sheets.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you so much for the response. I'm actually using a node-js library called `google-spreadsheet`, which I'm currently opting for the service account's credentials.json. I'll check out the access token.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you so much, John, I think I got it now. API keys will allow me to access any public google service, as they have no principal attached. They only do this to calculate quotas. So I'll start using the API keys and store them safely in the secrets manager (currently using AWS).